# How enum#feed works in ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

[`Enum#feed`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-feed)

> Sets the value to be returned by the next yield inside e.If 
>   the value is not set, the yield returns nil.This value is cleared after 
>   being yielded.

I tried one example but it is not the one I think to understand the 
`#feed` method.

```
a = [1,2,3,4].to_enum
p a.next #=> 1
a.feed 'foo'
p a.next #=> 2 , I expected here 'foo'
```

Can anyone give me a good example to understand how the `#feed` method 
works?

Comment: You're confusing `yield` with what the `next` method *yields* as a result.

Comment: @tadman i am not able to understand this method. Do you have a simple example with you,to explain this method. I am also not understand in what situation we should think about this method. Complete I am not educated with this method.

Comment: @toro2k helped me to provide an example -- [`#feed` method was the answer to my earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17082653/1153747).

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Thanks for the link. You can also see [`Enum#feed`](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4413849#1109566), I initiated in Ruby Forum for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation you linked to, it's up to the Enumerable object in question to decide what to do with your `feed` call. In this case, the default behavior is to ignore it. If you write your own custom Enumerable class, you could accept that and treat it as you will.

I have never seen `feed` used, but then again, it's the sort of thing that's put there for those occasions when you might need it. I can't think of a use for this thing at all, to be honest.

You'll have to test various things for support, but I'd be surprised if you find any objects that use it as you presume.