# Making map! enumerator do what I want

Tags: ruby

Having an array

```
a = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

And an enumerator:

```
e = a.map!
```

Then, by calling `e.next` repeatedly, array a gets nicely destroyed:

```
e.next #=> 1
a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
e.next #=> 2
a #=> [nil, 2, 3, 4]
e.next #=> 3
a #=> [nil, nil, 3, 4]
```

That's so hilarious! But when I try

```
e.next { |x| 2 * x } # => 4
```

I get

```
a #=> [nil, nil, nil, 4]
```

instead of desired

```
a #=> [nil, nil, nil, 8]
```

What am I misunderstanding? How to make `a.map!` do what I want with the elements?

My problem is, that I do not fully understand enumerators. With the previous code in place, for example, enumerator `e` constitutes a backdoor to `a`:

```
e.each { 42 }
a #=> [42, 42, 42, 42]
```

I would like to know, how to do this gradually, with values other than nil. (I can gradually fill it with nils using `e.rewind` and `e.next` several times, as I shown before.

Comment: The next method doesn't accept a block, so that would be the reason why nothing is happening. Can you show me some code where the `next` method would be useful?

Comment: @Zippie: It would have plenty of interesting uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `map!` behave as you want, you need the `Enumerator#feed` method, consider this

```
ary = *1..4
enum = ary.map!
# the `loop` method handles `StopIteration` for us
loop do
  x = enum.next
  enum.feed(x * 2)
end

ary
# => [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

From reference it seems that Enumerator#next doesn't accept a block, so that doesn't have effect of your `next` call. If you just want to in-place double the last element while clearing all other, do something like, consider straight approach (like `a = a[0..-2].map!{|x| nil} + [a.last*2]`, maybe more elegant). Anyway, could you please provide us with a more detailed usecase to make sure you are doing what you really need?

Comment: No, he wants to use a.next as a way to step through what map! would do to the contents iteration by iteration, which isn't how next is designed

Comment: Basically, my problem is that I do not fully understand enumerators.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, `#next` is designed solely for retrieving successor element in Enumerable instance, whereas `#each`, `#map` and so on are intended to provide a tool for working with whole range. Ruby's Enumerable is mostly functional by design (while not loosing beautiful Ruby's OOP features), so you may get more familiar with it, if you read some books on topic, for example, SICP (even if you'll read just the first parts of it, not the whole book). Also, you may try to write your own container (even duplicating existing functionality) and injecting Enumerable into it. It help'd me a lot.

Comment: @cdshines: I'll have to +1 you guys for trying to answer. But I have just now done what you and @Senjal suggest, that is through reading of `Enumerator` and `Enumerable` classes, and I found that my question here is really about `Enumerator`, not about `Enumerable` (which simply uses `#each` method to construct a bunch of useful enumerators). My issue here was with using enumerators in unusual ways. That's because enumerators are suugestive of functional programming, but as I discovered, can be wll used for those cases, where we don't really care about the return value, but want to modify the

Comment: @cdshines: receiver. And while I did it sometimes earlier, in constructs such as: `objects.each { |object| object.modify_yourself! }`, with `map!`, constructs like `a = [1, 2, 3]; e = a.map!; e.each { |x| x + 1 }` are possible, where the last statement does not really seem to modify anything, but it does. So, for example, I was interested in making a bubble sort enumerator such, that `e = a.bubble_sort!; e.each { |x, y| x > y ? [y, x] : [x, y] }`, or a game of life enumerator, or such. I feel it would have great use, but I cannot formulate it well why.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, such a 'severed' implementation seems a little bit hard to read for me. I mean, in one place you have an array, in other you create the (mutable) map of an array, and in another you perform an action on this. IMO it's better to have a Proc containing logic, an object (array in this case) and a call to enumerable tool of your choice with the Proc as an argument. At least you don't break application logic into unreadable pieces.

Comment: @cdshines: Indeed comments are not a place for major discussions, but I hope that you are at least getting a hint of what's excititng me here.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, yes, I do. I'm excited by Ruby's awesome features as well :)

Answer (score 1):

`a.map!` accepts a block, but returns an enumerator if no block is supplied. `Enumerator#next` does not accept a block.

You want to use this to accomplish your goal:

```
a.map! {|x| x * 2}
```

if you want to multiply all elements in the array by 2.

For info on next, check out http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next

If you want the output to be exactly `[nil, nil, nil, 8]` you could do something like:

```
func = lambda { |x|
  unless x == 4
    nil
  else
    x * 2
  end
}

a.map!(&func) #> [nil, nil, nil, 8]
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am an itnermediate-level Ruby user, I know how to use `map!` with a block, I know how to define lambdas, and I know how to browse `ruby-doc.org`. But provided that `#next` does not honor a block, then how can I take use of the `a.map!` enumerator, provided that it has already been demonstrated that it can replace `a` elements with `nil`s. What am I to to that enumerator to make it replace them with something else than `nil`s?

Comment: @sepp2k: It does not. Ruby methods cannot refuse a block, but can ignore it, and that is apparently what `next` method does.

Comment: An enumerator only goes through the list of elements in the array, that's it. Map! is not what you would use in this scenario. You're expecting it to do something it's not supposed to. e.next will set itself to the next element in that array, then you could do stuff knowing this. If you wanted to replace that element, you would have to know where the index is and replace it thusly based on the iterator. All in all, there are much better ways of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Why not just use the nondestructive method then?  You could get away with `a.each`.  Do you want to change the array from the enumerator object?  Is that your question?

Comment: @Senjai: The OP code proves that `a.map!` Enumerator instance retains the power to replace `a` elements. I want to control that power from that Enumerator instance.

Comment: I think the posted code proves it has the power to _consume_ elements, not to replace them with arbitrary values.

Comment: @squiguy: Because here, I am not solving a practical problem at hand, only investigating the `Enumerator` behavior. Long time ago, I needed to create "backlinks" to the array, to replace some of its elements with something else at a later time. Since then, I wanted to do something like this. Today, I learnt about `map!`, and I wonder if I can create a "backdoor link" to the array by constructing an enumerator, and then use it to modify the array later.

Comment: @AShelly /borisSitnicky, exactly. Because you use a destructive function the data will be consumed.

map! is defined in Array, not Enumerator, they belong to different classes.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky please compare:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html

Note that Array includes the Enumerable module which allows it to use the methods contained. An Enumerator (returned by map if no block is defined) is of Class Enumerator defined in the former. It has no "knowledge" of what created it. Just that it references a data set that created it. If you wanted to override next, you'd have to override next..